# Intuitive explanation of the bijection between $(-1,1)$ and $\Bbb R$

Tags: calculus, functions

I was reading Stephen Abbot's Understanding analysis and he uses $ f:(-1,1) \to \Bbb R$  $$f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2-1}$$ to show $(-1,1)$ and $\Bbb R$ have same cardinalty. This function seemed a bit alienating to me and I was wondering if you could give an intuitive explanation of why or how one may think of this function?

Comment: $f$ is an odd, strictly increasing, continuous function such that $\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}f(x)=+\infty$

Comment: If you want a function $f$ where $f(x)$ goes to infinity as $x$ goes to $1$ from below, then $1/(1-x)$ is simplest.  If $f(x)$ goes to $-\infty$ as $x$ goes to $-1$ from above, then $-1/(1+x)$ is simplest.  Average these two functions to get the simplest function that has both properties.

Answer (score 2):

You want to map the set of all reals less than $1$ and greater than $(-1)$ to the set of all reals. So, think of the only operation that can increase the magnitude of a value. It's division by a fraction! And that's exactly what we are doing. We want to divide $x\in (-1,1)$ by a number which is also in $(-1,1)$ because we want to go into the terretory of the reals.

I think a little more intuitive function can be
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$$
because it maps the positive part of $(-1,1)$, that is $(0,1)$ to the positive reals and the negative part of $(-1,1)$, that is $(-1,0)$ to the negative reals.

Comment: Your function only maps to $(-\infty,\frac12]$.

Comment: @StefanAlbrecht Oh! Yes! Thanks for pointing it out. I must have messed something up in my mind!

Answer (score 2):

We show that your function $f \colon (-1, 1) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f(x) := \frac{x}{x^2-1}
$$
is bijective.

Suppose that $u, v \in (-1, 1)$ such that $f(u) = f(v)$. That is,
$$
\frac{u}{u^2-1} = \frac{v}{v^2-1}.
$$
Then
$$
u \left( v^2 - 1 \right) = v \left( u^2 - 1 \right).
$$
So
$$
u^2 v - v - u v^2 + u = 0,
$$
which is the same as
$$
u^2v - u v^2 + u-v = 0,
$$
which in turn is the same as
$$
(u-v) (uv + 1) = 0. \tag{1}
$$
Now as $-1 < u < 1$ and $-1 < v < 1$, so $-1 < uv < 1$, and thus $uv + 1 \neq 0$, and then (1) implies that $u = v$.

Thus, for any points $u, v \in (-1, 1)$, if $f(u) = f(v)$, then we must have $u = v$. So $f$ is injective.

Next, we show that $f$ is surjective. For this, let $y$ be any real number. Then there exists an $x \in (-1, 1)$ for which $f(x) = y$ if and only if
$$
\frac{x}{x^2-1} = y,
$$
which holds if and only if
$$
x = y \left( x^2 - 1 \right),
$$
which in turn holds if and only if
$$
y x^2 - x - y = 0. \tag{2} 
$$
If $y = 0$, then (2) holds if and only if $x = 0$. And, if $y \neq 0$, then (2) holds if and only if
$$
x = \frac{ 1 \pm \sqrt{ 1 + 4y^2 } }{2 y }.
$$
But as $-1 < x < 1$, so (2) holds if and only if
$$
x = \frac{ 1 - \sqrt{ 1 + 4y^2 } }{2 y }.
$$
Thus, for any real number $y$, we can find a point $x \in (-1, 1)$ such that $y = f(x)$, showing that $f$ is surjective.

Therefore your function $f$ is bijective. Hence $(-1, 1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: What has your answer to do with “an intuitive explanation of why or how one may think of this function”?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to come up with bijections between these two sets, not all share the same level of elegance as the one in  question, but then again, a it is not so surprising when a first attempt lacks perfection compared to something published in a book. What I want to say is that you do not have to despair that you might perhaps never have come up with the specific example - on the one hand, it doesn't matter, and on the other hand, working through such examples will undoubtedly sharpen your intuition simply by filling up your mental utility belt.

So how might one come up with a suitable bijection *from scratch*? The apparent obstacle is that $(-1,1)$ is bounded whereas $\Bbb R$ reaches out to infinity. Perhaps the most natural idea of a function that maps something small to something big then is the map $x\mapsto \frac1x$. Unfortunately, this does not solve our problem:

- It is not even defined at $x=0$
- It maps $(0,1)\to (1,\infty)$
- It maps $(-1,0)\to (-\infty,-1)$

So we have a one-point gap in the domain and also a big gap $[-1,1]$ in the range. But the can get rid of both by shifting the two open intervals together and using $0$ as "mortar":
$$f(x):=\begin{cases}\frac1x-1&x>0\\\frac1x+1&x<0\\0&x=0\end{cases} $$
So here we are, a valid solution to th eproblem. Once you have it, you may think if it can be improved. That $0$ is really disturbing.  The original idea of $x\mapsto \frac1x$ would be better suited for $(0,1)$ or $(-1,0)$, where the singularity is at one of the boundary points. Hm, to have the singularity at one of the boundary points of $(-1,1)$, we might want $x\mapsto \frac1{x+1}$ or $x\mapsto \frac1{x-1}$. But each of these seems to solve only halve the problem, they are not onto. So perhaps combine them? Then you may certainly play with things like $$x\mapsto \frac a{x+1}+\frac b{x-1}$$ for various constants $a,b$  and find something nice.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped!

Answer (score 1):

The important thing about $f$ is that it is a bijection: every value in $\mathbb R$ is reached as $f(x)$ for some $x\in(-1,1)$, and no two distinct $x,y\in(-1,1)$ satisfy $f(x)=f(y)$.

When trying to construct such a bijection, it first makes sense to restrict to continuous functions. This has nothing to do with the "same cardinality" property -- continuous functions are just an easier set of functions to think about.

Now, if $f$ maps $(-1,1)$ continuously and bijectively to $\mathbb R$, it should tend towards infinity as $x\to 1$ or $x\to -1$; otherwise, it's hard to get both arbitrarily large positive and negative values. One of the simplest ways to get a function that goes to $\infty$ somewhere is to take the reciprocal of a function that goes to $0$ there. A simple function that is $0$ at $1$ is $x-1$, and a simple function that is $0$ at $-1$ is $x+1$, so it makes sense to pick $x^2-1$ as our simple function that is $0$ at both $-1$ and $1$. So, we guess that $f(x)$ should look something like $\frac1{x^2-1}$.

Unfortunately, the function $f(x)=\frac1{x^2-1}$ is neither injective nor surjective; it both repeats and misses values. In essence, this is because it goes to $-\infty$ both near $1$ and $-1$, while we want it to go to $+\infty$ at one of $\{-1,1\}$ and $-\infty$ at the other. The simplest way to reverse this trend is to multiply it by something that's positive at $1$ (say) and negative at $-1$, for which $x$ is a reasonable choice. This gives $f(x)=\frac x{x^2-1}$.

Comment: Thank you so much ! The idea of restricting to continuous function and then trying to take it to infinity as x tends to an endpoint made the choice of this function much more clear to me